# Improve MySQL Performance

Tags: mysql, linux, multithreading, python-3.x, pymysql

Info:
MySQL Community 5.7.12 64 bits

Programming Language:
Python 3.5

mysqld.cnf: 
[Mysqld.cnf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4bFyKclRxLCMEtnOW8zSTVnYWc/view?usp=sharing)

result of "show variables"
[show variables](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SaprFqc6HwB9Ou2QwP1aTMi5DG39UNd4leLxIE5rFlo)

Description:
- I have 200 000 tasks.
- I process these tasks with 500 threads, one per task, when a thread finishes, another task start. The point of this is not to have more than 500 threads running. 
- I am creating a connection per thread. (pymysql)
- Every one of this thread does about 350 inserts into a table whit the query "insert ignore".
- This are very basic inserts in a table with 12 columns.

I have a server with the following specs:
SO: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
RAM: 32 GB
Procesor: 6 core 2.66 GHz
Number of procesors: 2
HDD: 10K RPM SAS 2.5"
Virtual Cores: 24 cores.

The problem I have is that is taking a lot of time to do the inserts in database, with a average of 1000 seconds per thread.

How Can I improve this? with this question I put the links of mysqld.cnf and the result of show variables y csv format.

Please any advise?

Thanks!

Comment: you should better provide code fragment

Comment: Instead of 350 seperate inserts can you do smaller batches with multi-insert syntax?

Comment: Jared Beekman, I can try that. I will test it tonight and commend about the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of Jared  Beekman, I was able to optmize this.
I put together all the queries and the result was a 100 time faster process.